# VBA regex - Value used in formula is of the wrong data type

Tags: regex, vba

I can't seem to figure out why this function which includes a regex keeps returning an error of wrong data type? I'm trying to return a match to the identified pattern from a file path string in an excel document. An example of the pattern I'm looking for is "02 Package_2018-1011" from a sample string "H:\H1801100 MLK Middle School Hartford\2-Archive! Issued Bid Packages\01 Package_2018-0905 Demolition and Abatement Bid Set_Drawings - PDF\00 HazMat\HM-1.pdf". Copy of the VBA code is listed below.

```
Function textpart(Myrange As Range) As Variant
Dim strInput As String
Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

strInput = Myrange.Value

With regex
    .Pattern = "\D{2}\sPackage_\d{4}-\d{4}"
    .Global = True
End With

Set textpart = regex.Execute(strInput)
```

End Function

Comment: Possibly `\\` is seen as an escape character that you must escape...with a backslash.

Comment: `02 Package_2018-1011` is not present in `H:\H1801100 MLK Middle School Hartford\2-Archive\! Issued Bid Packages\01 Package_2018-0905 Demolition and Abatement Bid Set\_Drawings - PDF\00 HazMat\HM-1.pdf`. Also, `\D` matches any char but a digit, you need `\d{2}` at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\d{2}` to match 2-digit chunk, not `\D{2}`. Besides, you are trying to assign the whole match collection to the function result, while you should extract the first match value and assign that value to the function result:

```
Function textpart(Myrange As Range) As Variant
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")


    strInput = Myrange.Value

    With regex
        .Pattern = "\d{2}\sPackage_\d{4}-\d{4}"
    End With

    Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
      textpart = matches(0).Value
    End If

End Function
```

Note that to match it as a whole word you may add word boundaries:

```
.Pattern = "\b\d{2}\sPackage_\d{4}-\d{4}\b"
            ^^                          ^^
```

To only match it after `\`, you may use a capturing group:

```
.Pattern = "\\(\d{2}\sPackage_\d{4}-\d{4})\b"
' ...
' and then
' ...
textpart = matches(0).Submatches(0)
```